# How to share a folder between two computers on different networks?

Tags: network-shares, home-networking, shared-folders

I'm trying to create a folder that can be shared between my home and work computers (both Win 7, not on same network). Ideally I want to have folder on both computers desktops and be able to change its contents easily from both computers. How I can do this? 
Thank you.

Comment: Virtually any online synchronisation tool worth its weight in genuine imitation ovalquik would do this. I'd take a look at dropbox and bitorrent sync. There's too many other options to list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And Cloud based syncing service will do the job.

Some examples:
 - Dropbox.com
 - Copy.com
 - Box.com
 - Skydrive.com (From Microsoft)
 - Google Drive
 - and etc..

If you want to avoid cloud but still sync files then Bittorrent.com/sync is a good option.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like to use cloud services, you could setup a VPN tunnel between the computers in cause. Afterwards it's just a matter of sharing permissions.